# What's the fastest way to sync a node only keeping full state for the last N blocks?

Tags: sync, state, pruning

I need to only keep `state` for the last few blocks, but I don't want to wait for the full sync of the node, is there a way to do that faster than by using `--sync=full`? Because it seems like all the current modes either download the `full history` or just the latest state.

Answer (score 1):

Check this guide from the Polkadot Wiki: [Set up a Full Node](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-sync). Running as a simple sync node, only the state of the past 256 blocks will be kept, if you want all the history [run as an Archive Node](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-sync#running-an-archive-node).

If you want a faster sync you can use the flag `--sync warp`

```sh
--sync <SYNC_MODE>
    Blockchain syncing mode.
    
    - `full`: Download and validate full blockchain history.
    - `fast`: Download blocks and the latest state only.
    - `fast-unsafe`: Same as `fast`, but skip downloading state proofs.
    - `warp`: Download the latest state and proof.
```

More information about why is faster: [Is GRANDPA warp sync the recommended method for syncing a node?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5855/is-grandpa-warp-sync-the-recommended-method-for-syncing-a-node) and in the [Polkadot Protocol Specification](https://spec.polkadot.network/chap-sync#sect-sync-warp).